# Extract specific text from URL Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract specific text from many urls that are being returned.
Im using Python 2.7 with requests and BeautifulSoup.

The reason is i need to find the latest URL which can be identified by the highest number "DF_7" with 7 been the highest from the below urls.This url will then be downloaded.
Note, each day new files are added, this is why i need to check for the one with the highest number.

Once i find the highest number in the list of URL's i then need to join
this "https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi/SC/servicing/" to the url with the highest number.
The final product should look like this.
https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi/SC/servicing/downloads.php?Reference=DF_7&SortField=ExpiryDays&SortOrder=Ascending

The urls look like this just with DF_ incrementing each time

Is this the right approach? if so how do i go about doing this.

Thanks

```
import base
import requests
import zipfile, StringIO, re
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from base import os

from django.conf import settings

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
    'option': 'login'
}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.

with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post('https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi?option=login', data=payload)

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get('https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi/SC/servicing/downloads.php?Folder=DataDownloads&SortField=ExpiryDays&SortOrder=Ascending', stream=True)
    content = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    links = table.find_all('a')
    print links
```

Comment: Have you got any code for this?

Comment: yes, i will amend my post now

Comment: Could you add the links your script prints please?

Comment: <a class="tabletd" href="downloads.php?Reference=DF_7&amp;SortField=ExpiryDays&amp;SortOrder=Ascending">

Comment: Is the link you want always the last link on the page with the class tabletd?

Comment: yes, it should be the last

Comment: You have put too much specific detail into your question, IMHO - Surely the issue is : given an array of similar strings, identify the one with the highest numeric value in a given position ...

Comment: @MikeW I'd like to disagree. The question was "is this the right approach" my answer was like don't bother creating a list of string objects and identify which one has the highest numerical value at a given position but go straight to it without creating all those string objects. Easier to read and less code.

Comment: Thanks Dan-Dev, the below worked, now just to join that to the URL so i can download it. Im pretty new to python coding so i rather made sure i gave as much detail in the post than to little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go straight to the last link with the class "tableid" and print it's href value like this:

```
href = soup.find_all("a", {'class':'tabletd'})[-1]['href']
base = "https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi/SC/servicing/"
print (base + href)
```